# Android AsyncTask Volley

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have some issue. I have my async class inside Activity. . i Cant return nothing to onPostMethod. Should i use some design pattern, like Factory to make this more generic? What my point is. After i get json with data. I should finished my "spinner", but in this ProcccesDialog never ends becouse it never recieve any data from doInBackGround method. Thanks for any advaice

```
 private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void ,String>k{
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){



       // ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "text..");
        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this,"","Please Wait",false);


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
           RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
        String url = args[0];
        Log.d("port", port);
        Log.d("host", host);
        Log.d("URL:", url);
        final VolleyCallback callback = null;


        final JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String json = response.toString();
                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        try {
                            user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (user != null) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("host", host);
                            intent.putExtra("port", port);
                            intent.putExtra("appName", appName);
                            intent.putExtra("user", user); //zeby przekazac "implements Serializable
                            //User user =(User)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user"); <-- żeby odebrać w 2 Activity
                            startActivity(intent);

                            if (user.getImie() != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Witaj " + user.getImie(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }else if (json == null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Błędny login lub hasło" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString())




                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Host1991 ", String.valueOf(isHostReachable(host)));
                        if(user == null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Błędy login lub hasło", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(!isHostReachable(host)){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());

                        }


                    }

                }


        );
        queue.add(getRequest);
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String success) {
       // spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            dialog.dismiss();


    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to start `MainActivity` in your background thread.  If  that starts the main part of your app after login, that's not good.  Also, for updating UI while you're in the background thread, use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with your code is that you are calling your intent in "DoInBackground()" method, you activity starts changing before the compiler reach to the "OnPostMethod".
The best way I can suggest you is to declare your intent variable in global scope and move the "StartActivity(intent)" method call in "OnPost" method.
Or initialize some variables in global scope those you need, and access them in "OnPost()" method and call your intent there.

Answer (score 0):

Do away with the AsyncTask.

No need to do a Volley call in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask.

Wrong desing. Bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AsyncTask or any other Thread mechanism if you are using 'Volley', because 'Volley' itself manage Thread. It perform Network operation on worker thread and will give to response on 'Main Thread(UI Thread).